# Display any multi-dimensional array as a html table

Tags: php, html, arrays

I use [this function](http://aidanlister.com/2004/04/converting-arrays-to-human-readable-tables/) to display any kind of multi-dimensional array as a human readeable html table. For exemple, this array :

```
$arr = array
(
  'root' => array(
    'main' => array (
      'members' => array(
        array ('identifier' => '36', 'fullname' => 'jonathan carter'),
        array ('identifier' => '42', 'fullname' => 'hello world')
      )
    )
  )
);
```

becomes a table (with `echo array2table($arr, true)`) :

[image: html table]

My problem, as you can see, is that there are too many table headers when multiple arrays contains only one sub array. This is what I would like to have :

[image]

You probably say: "What did you tried ?"
Well, before displaying the table header, I made and call a recursive function which returns an array of keys if there nested tables :

```
function nextTableHeaders($array)
{
    // requires an array with only 1 child
    if (!is_array($array) || count($array) !== 1)
        return array();

    $key = key($array);

    return array_merge(array($key), nextTableHeaders($array[$key]));
}
```

In that case, it returns :

```
array('root', 'main', 'members');
```

Then I join the values with ' > ' and it becomes my new table headers. But I need then to go deeper into the arrays (because I don't wan't to display "main > members", and "members"). But I didn't succeed.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I actually couldn't agree more with @Anthony on this one!

Comment: So he hasn't gotten to the CSS yet.

Comment: `$arr_path = array('root', 'main', 'members'); $path = ''; foreach($arr_path as $v){ $path .= '['.$v.']'; }`
and then access to your deeper array by `$deeper = ${'arr'.$path}`

Comment: @mclaassen, this is not about the form, it's about the content. I did not use CSS for this example.

Comment: @AsKaiser-FR Yes I know. I was defending you against Anthony's remark.

Comment: now i'm just confused. CSS to make it more beautiful? I don't think that's even possible... And if it's about the content, you should collapse the headers/keys into a string, as that makes the table less semantically true. If it were possible (not sure it is, but don't think it can be done) then CSS actually would be the right way to go, since the apparent goal is to make the headers more visually appealing/approachable, not to make the table more true to the underlying data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to keep the table printing as is, and to create a new function that will take the array and then convert it into the sort of array which when printed will display what you wish to be displayed.

```
function compressArray($array) {
    // Non-arrays and multiple-key arrays are unaffected
    if (!is_array($array) or count($array) !== 1)
        return $array;

    // This is a recursive algorithm
    $child = compressArray(current($array));

    // Compression unnecessary when child is non-array or a multiple-key array
    if (!is_array($child) or count($child) !== 1)
        return $array;

    // Both parent and child are single key arrays so compress
    $new_key = key($array) . " > " . key($child);
    return array($new_key => current($child));
}
```

This will convert

```
$arr = array
(
    'root' => array(
        'main' => array (
            'members' => array(
                array ('identifier' => '36', 'fullname' => 'jonathan carter'),
                array ('identifier' => '42', 'fullname' => 'hello world')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

into

```
$arr = array
(
    'root > main > members' => array(
        array ('identifier' => '36', 'fullname' => 'jonathan carter'),
        array ('identifier' => '42', 'fullname' => 'hello world')
    )
);
```